# How can I remove the white background in a webview?

Tags: android, html, xml, webview

I have the following problem: I am loading a html file into a webview. The background color of my html file and my activity is black. What happens is that there is a short white flash at the beginning when finished loading because the background color of the webview is white.

Can I remove that flash? Or set that webview color to black? I already tried setting the background color in the webview xml to black, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.
Try:

```
webview.setBackgroundResource(Color.Black);
```

Comment: So funny that five years later it still has to be set programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this solved it for me:

Just below the existing

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

I added the line

```
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

To do any good it must be before

```
mWebView.loadUrl(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove background completely (transparent):

```java
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

setting background (xml or programmatically) didn't work for me, just use `CustomTabs` it's faster so this issue didn't seem to matter. Especially if you use the optimizations (`warmup` and `mayLaunchUrl`) detailed here:
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/an-introduction-to-chrome-custom-tabs-for-android